# Intermittent difficulty access Facebook.com

Tags: windows-10, browser

I am using Windows 10 and Chrome (both up-to-date) and can usually access Facebook.com. However, every few days I get the message

> This site can’t be reached
> The connection was reset.
> Try:
> •   Checking the connection
> •   Checking the proxy and the firewall
> •   Running Windows Network Diagnostics
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

It is only Facebook that is a problem. I have tried also with Edge and get the same result. Switching to a different user on the same computer results in the same error message. The only solution is to reboot the computer. I am using ESET Internet Security as a firewall etc. I have a different PC on the same network that does not have this problem. The only difference is that that the PC with the problem uses a Wi-Fi (mesh) whereas the other is a wired connection to the router.

I am completely baffled and would welcome any thoughts on the cause and a fix.

Comment: Try a different device.  Might be DNS on your router.

Comment: @John Thanks, tried that too. I have a different PC on the same network that has no problems.

Comment: Maybe try a Windows 10 Repair install on the problem machine. Use the Microsoft Media Creation Link, second link, and Keep Everything.

Comment: The following gives a reasonably comprehensive selection of checks to make when seeing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors in Chrome and might help in identifying the root cause: https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/

Comment: @MikeParker Thanks, I'll try those as soon as it goes again.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Network troubleshooter. The Network troubleshooter can help diagnose and fix common connection problems.

**Method 1:**

To run the Network troubleshooter

Select the Start  button > Settings > Network & Internet > Status.
Open Network & Internet Status

Under Change your network settings, select Network troubleshooter.

Follow the steps in the troubleshooter, and see if that fixes the problem.
If the issue remains try method 2

**Method 2.**

Uninstall the network adapter driver and restart

If the previous steps didn’t work, try to uninstall the network adapter driver, and then restart your computer. Windows will automatically install the latest driver. Consider this approach if your network connection stopped working properly after a recent update.

Before uninstalling, make sure you have drivers available as a backup. Visit the PC manufacturer’s website and download the latest network adapter driver from there. If your PC can't connect to the internet, you'll need to download a driver on a different PC and save it to a USB flash drive so you can install the driver on your PC. You’ll need to know the PC manufacturer and model name or number.

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type Device Manager, and then
   select Device Manager from the list of results.
2. Expand Network adapters, and locate the network adapter for your
   device.
3. Select the network adapter, press and hold (or right-click), and
   then select Uninstall device > the Attempt to remove the driver
   software for this device check box > Uninstall.
4. After uninstalling the driver, select the Start  button > Power  >
   Restart.

After your PC restarts, Windows will automatically look for and install the network adapter driver. Check to see if that fixes your connection problem. If Windows doesn't automatically install a driver, try to install the backup driver you saved before uninstalling.